# Why does std::remove_if think a shared_ptr<T> is a predicate?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have the simple example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct foo
{};


int main(void)
{
  vector<shared_ptr<foo>> v;

  auto f1 = make_shared<foo>();
  auto f2 = make_shared<foo>();
  auto f3 = make_shared<foo>();
  auto f4 = make_shared<foo>();

  v.push_back(f1);
  v.push_back(f2);
  v.push_back(f3);
  v.push_back(f4);

  cout << v.size() << endl;

  v.erase(remove_if(begin(v), end(v), f2), end(v));

  cout << v.size() << endl;
}
```

Why does this `remove_if` think that `f2` is a predicate rather than a value that I'm looking for? Do I really have to provide a predicate here to get this to work - or what am I doing wrong here?

(NOTE: compiler: gcc 4.8.2 -std=c++11)

EDIT: Should have rtfm! Anyway - here is the compiler output:

```
In file included from /usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from remove_if.cpp:4:
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<foo>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo> > >; _Predicate = std::shared_ptr<foo>]':
remove_if.cpp:29:41:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:1150:33: error: no match for call to '(std::shared_ptr<foo>) (std::shared_ptr<foo>&)'
         if(!bool(__pred(*__first)))
                                 ^
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<foo>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo> > >; _Predicate = std::shared_ptr<foo>]':
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4465:41:   required from '_IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<foo>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo> > >; _Predicate = std::shared_ptr<foo>]'
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:1144:64:   required from '_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<foo>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo> > >; _Predicate = std::shared_ptr<foo>]'
remove_if.cpp:29:41:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:214:23: error: no match for call to '(std::shared_ptr<foo>) (std::shared_ptr<foo>&)'
    if (__pred(*__first))
                       ^
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:218:23: error: no match for call to '(std::shared_ptr<foo>) (std::shared_ptr<foo>&)'
    if (__pred(*__first))
                       ^
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:222:23: error: no match for call to '(std::shared_ptr<foo>) (std::shared_ptr<foo>&)'
    if (__pred(*__first))
                       ^
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:226:23: error: no match for call to '(std::shared_ptr<foo>) (std::shared_ptr<foo>&)'
    if (__pred(*__first))
                       ^
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:234:23: error: no match for call to '(std::shared_ptr<foo>) (std::shared_ptr<foo>&)'
    if (__pred(*__first))
                       ^
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:238:23: error: no match for call to '(std::shared_ptr<foo>) (std::shared_ptr<foo>&)'
    if (__pred(*__first))
                       ^
/usr/local/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:242:23: error: no match for call to '(std::shared_ptr<foo>) (std::shared_ptr<foo>&)'
    if (__pred(*__first))
```

Comment: This confusion would have been a lot clearer with some compiler output and the output that you expected instead.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. I don't get the point of confusion

Comment: I would delete, but Mike has answered correctly already, so I won't delete, but if it does get closed - so be it..

Comment: @Nim You can fix it, just mention the error.  Then it's a search entry point for people trying to remove items with remove_if but who don't want a predicate and don't know about remove.  It was just a bit of an important oversight not to mention the code wasn't compiling...

Comment: Despite it pending, this should NOT be closed as "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." - it can be reproduced, and it's not typographical it's mistaken use of a distinct function.

Comment: @TonyD: This close reason is used when the OP simply made a silly error and/or didn't read the documentation and/or made a typo and/or such like. It's usually accompanied by "oh, silly me" or "d'oh" in comments (see below). The problem was unique to the OP's failure to read XYZ documentation and, as such, the question is unlikely to be relevant to anyone else ever. Remember, this is a repository of information, not a personal helpdesk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's what `remove_if` does; the third argument is a predicate to test whether to remove an element. Presumably, your code fails to compile since `shared_ptr` can't be called like a function.

If you want to remove elements with a particular value, use [`remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: And how is `std::shared_ptr<foo>` a predicate? I would have thought that this would fail to compile without an `operator()`.

Comment: arrgggh!!! Just noticed the bloody documentation (it's on the same page on cppreference...) doh!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It isn't. But `remove_if` will try to treat it as one, presumably failing to compile.

Comment: @Mike: Okay, to be fair, I guess, the OP didn't actually say that his code compiles.

Comment: @Nim: it's plausible that someone else might hit the same problem - I don't see the question need be deleted.  Separately, hopefully some form of Concepts will come in with a future Standard and make it easier for programmers to appreciate what they've done wrong in such cases.